# pq: function unnest(unknown) is not unique

Tags: arrays, postgresql, go, pq

Following code is working fine. But I want to define array['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'] as a variable.

```
rows, err :=  db.Query("select colname from (SELECT date, unnest(array['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']) AS colname, unnest(array[a, b, c, d, e]) AS thing from test1 where date='123') as tester where thing=1;")
```

So I try following code using github.com/lib/pq .

```
arr1 := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}      
rows, err :=  db.Query("select colname from (SELECT date, unnest($1) AS colname, unnest($1) AS thing from test1 where date='123') as tester where thing=1;", pq.Array(arr1))
```

But getting error like "pq: function unnest(unknown) is not unique".
Table structure and sample data--

```
test=# \d+ test1
                                Table "public.test1"
 Column |         Type          | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------
 a      | character varying(10) |           | extended |              | 
 b      | character varying(10) |           | extended |              | 
 c      | character varying(10) |           | extended |              | 
 d      | character varying(10) |           | extended |              | 
 e      | character varying(10) |           | extended |              | 
 date   | character varying(10) |           | extended |              | 

test=# select * from test1 ;
 a | b | c | d | e | date 
---+---+---+---+---+------
 3 | 1 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 124
 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 125
 1 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 3 | 126
 1 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 127
 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 123
(5 rows)
```

Basically I want the column name (a,b,c,d or e) which have value '1' on any specific date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL 9.3: Function is not unique error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34431315/postgresql-9-3-function-is-not-unique-error)

Comment: Not expert in `postgresql` but in c# with standard sql i would create array of characters, then merge them with separator ", " and then use it as parameter.

Comment: @AleksaRistic PostgreSQL has array types (which AFAIK are standard SQL even though hardly anyone supports them).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'd guess that `pq.Array` is giving you a PostgreSQL array in the string form so you end up with something like this:

```
unnest('{a,b,c,d,e}')
```

and PostgreSQL isn't sure how it should interpret that string, hence the complaint about `unnest(unknown)`. You should be able to add an explicit type cast to clear things up:

```
unnest($1::text[])         -- PostgreSQL-specific casting syntax
unnest(cast($1 as text[])) -- Standard casting syntax
```

You'd end up with something like this:

```
rows, err :=  db.Query("select colname from (SELECT date, unnest($1::text[]) AS colname, unnest($1) AS thing from test1 where date='123') as tester where thing=1;", pq.Array(arr1))
```

Comment: There is something wrong happened when variable substitute in 2nd unnest. When I uses 
rows, err := db.Query("select colname from (SELECT date, unnest($1::text[]) AS colname, unnest(array[a, b, c, d, e]) AS thing from test1 where date='123') as tester where thing='1';", pq.Array(arr1))
It is giving right output .But when uses following code I found no error and no output.
rows, err :=  db.Query("select colname from (SELECT date, unnest($1::text[]) AS colname, unnest($1) AS thing from test1 where date='123') as tester where thing=1;", pq.Array(arr1))

Comment: What happens if you try the query in `psql`?

Comment: test=# select colname from (SELECT date, unnest(array['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']) AS colname, unnest(array[a, b, c, d, e]) AS thing from test1 where date='123') as tester where thing='1';

colname 
---------
 a
 b
(2 rows)

Comment: It gives 2 outputs a and b.

Comment: You're going to have to include the table structure and some sample data in your question.

Comment: Updated the description

Comment: I'd recommend asking a new question with those new details and a description of you're trying to get your query to do, tag it with "sql" and "postgresql". You have an XY-problem and you're trying to solve the wrong problem (you want to solve "how do I get my desired results" rather than "how do I make *this* query work").

Comment: Ok I have created a new question . Thanks for help.