# node-postgres: function unnest(unknown) is not unique

Tags: node.js, postgresql, aws-lambda, node-postgres

I'm trying to run an AWS Lambda which upserts data into a Postgres (RDS) table

Here's my table structure:

| id(integer) | name(character varying) | marks(decimal) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | derp | 42 |
| 2 | derpina | 45.5 |

My upsert query which runs perfectly on my local pgAdmin console:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (
    id, name, 
    marks) 
    VALUES (
        unnest(ARRAY[1,4,3]::integer[]), 
        unnest(ARRAY['derp','frog','doge']::string[]), 
        unnest(ARRAY[100,50.0,122]::decimal[])
    ) ON CONFLICT 
    ON CONSTRAINT pkey
    DO UPDATE
    SET 
    marks=excluded.marks;
```

My code snippet:

```
const pg = require("pg");
const Pool = pg.Pool;
var query = "INSERT INTO mytable (id, name, marks) VALUES (unnest($1::integer[]),unnest($2::string[]), unnest($3::decimal[])) ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT pkey DO UPDATE SET marks=excluded.marks;"
var row = [];
var ids = [1,4,3];
var names = ['derp','tom','jerry'];
var marks = [100,44.5,31];
row.push(ids);
row.push(names);
row.push(marks);
// more code on starting up pool connection, etc...
client.query(query, row, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("DB upsert error: ", err.stack);
    } else {
        console.log("upserted " + res.rowCount + " entries");
    }
});
```

My error:

```
function unnest(unknown) is not unique
```

I already tried the solution suggested in [pq: function unnest(unknown) is not unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52678372/pq-function-unnestunknown-is-not-unique), [unnest(unknown) is not unique](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1776) and [unnest(array) returns text instead of the actual type](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/2425) but nothing seems to suggest the solution.
Please help!